# Find 'N' numbers whose XOR is equal to 'X' with Minimum Values

Tags: discrete-mathematics

You are given two natural numbers N and X. You are required to create an array of N natural numbers such that bitwise XOR of these numbers is equal to X. The sum of all the natural numbers that are available in the array is as minimum as possible.
sample Input:
**N=3, X=2**
Sample output :
**1 1 2**
Explanation:
We have to print 3 natural numbers having the minimum sum
Thus the N-spaced numbers are [1 1 2]

Comment: Do you consider $\ 0\ $ to be a natural number?

Comment: Really? Then $\mathbf{\ 0\ 0\ 2\ }$ is the best answer to the $\mathbf{\ 3\ 2\ }$ challenge.

Comment: It seems a programming exercise..

Comment: Sorry zeros are not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Take $N-1$ copies of $0$ and 1 copy of $X$, with sum $X$.

Edit: if $0$ is not allowed, the minimum sum is
$$\begin{cases}
X &\text{if $w(X) \ge N$},\\
X + 2\left\lceil\frac{N - w(X)}{2}\right\rceil &\text{otherwise},\\
\end{cases}$$
where $w(X)$ is the number of bits in $X$.

Comment: Sorry but elements of N can't be zero